# jQuery DataTables - Export as Excel attachment and send mail

Tags: java, excel, email, datatables, client-side

We are using jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin in our application.  Normally there would be 5 to 10 columns in the datatable with 50 rows per page and the pages would range from 1 to 20.

Now, we are introducing an email functionality in the application, wherein users can select any row(s) from the datatable and click on **Send Mail** button.  The requirement is, when the user clicks on *Send Mail* button, the selected row(s) data should be exported to Excel & attached as an attachment in a mail and then sent to the mail recipients.

My question is, is it possible to implement a solution for this *Send Mail* functionality on the client-side, that is exporting selected row(s) data to Excel, attaching it as an attachment and then sending a mail?  If so, what are all the possible solutions/suggestions?

Any other server-side based suggestions/solutions are also welcome.

**EDIT**: Server-side language is Java.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which server side language do you use, php, python, c?

Comment: @HddnTHA - Updated my question.  Server-side language is Java.

Comment: Can you please tag your question with `java`, then `java` tag subscribers can see your question. I am not familiar of java, good luck.